# Error while trying to show route:list in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, controller, routes

I'am trying to use an API in laravel 5.4,and while executing in command-line 'php artisan route:list' to retreive all site routes, but unfortunately i get this error :

> [ReflectionException]
>     Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\CausesController.php does not exist

this is my Controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Cause;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreCausesRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\UpdateCausesRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\FileUploadTrait;

class CausesController extends Controller
{
use FileUploadTrait;

public function index()
{
    return Cause::all();
}

}
```

and this is my api.php :

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' =>    'api.'], function () {

Route::resource('causes', 'CausesController.php');

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On route resource, controller name must be "'CausesController". So, delete .php ext.

Comment: Thanks it **works** like a sharm now. Even that such problems mustn't be done.